# How to add/active an AuthenticationProvider without using it within the firewall?

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

What is the correct way to add a `AuthenticationProvider` to the kernel? Creating a dummy entry in the `security.yml` file works but seems to be quite hacky.

**Long story:**

I am working on creating a Amazon Alexa Skill for my existing Symfony based web services.

To check wether a request should be authorized I have to manually extract the `AuthToken` from the request and pass it to the `AuthenticationManager`:

```
public function alexaRequestAction(Request $request, AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager) {
    ...
    $accessToken = $this->getAuthTokenFromRequest($request);       

    if ($accessToken) {
        $token = new OAuthToken();
        $token->setToken($accessToken);

        try {
            $authToken = $authenticationManager->authenticate($token);                
            ...
        } catchcatch (AuthenticationException $e) {
            ...
        }  
    } else {
        // Request without a linked account...
    }
}
```

This fails with a `ProviderNotFoundException`. If I add some logging to `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager` to see which providers are available the `OAuthProvider` is not included.

I can change this by adding a dummy entry to the firewall settings:

```
// security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        oauth_dummy:
            pattern   : ^/someDummyPath
            fos_oauth : true
```

Now the provider is available and the code above works. However adding a dummy firewall just to add the provider seems not be the most elegant solution. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: have a good read of [Guard](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/security/guard_authentication.html)

Comment: Thanks @DevDonkey but this article describes how to create a custom authentication system while the question is on how to use an existing authentication system (FOSOAuthServerBundle). Or is the answer "Authentication systems should not be used manually but only by the firewall? Create custom system which extracts the token from the quest and wraps the existing OAuth authentication"?

Comment: as far as I know, if you want to leverage Symfony's auth configuration youll need to do it via a firewall entry.   Or if not you could override the whole thing and just go in via a controller method, but tbh I'd not bother.  Additional firewalls are fine.

Comment: If you need it in the whole system, why don't you just add it under the firewall with root (`^/`) path or wherever you need it?

Comment: @DevDonkey I thought about "Overriding the whole thing" but this comes with some other problems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748949  @DonCallisto I do not need it in the whole system but only in one controller. Adding a firewall for this path/controller is not possible since `fos_oauth` does not recognize the was Alexa transfers the token. Additionally Alexa uses the same path/controller both for authorized and unauthorized requests.